# python flask URL error: 'The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.'

Tags: python, flask

When I try to apply the url route I got this error.
Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@api.route('/GET/collections/<id>/<year>?q=<query>')
class DataRetrive(Resource):
    def get(self,id, year, query):
        return 'yes'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need specify the query parameter "q"

try something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@api.route('/GET/collections/<id>/<year>')
class DataRetrive(Resource):
    def get(self,id, year):
        q = request.args.get('q')
        return 'yes'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Pay attention to the country parameter that you have not defined ...

So your url looks like this:

localhost:5000/GET/collections/1/2020?q=something